# Stability of counting sort

Tags: python, sorting, counting-sort

I have implemented a counting sort algorithm in python. I see that counting sort is Stable as it preserves the order of the element in the original Array. Do you think that the below implementation is stable ?

```
    def countingsort(A,n):
        C = [0]*n
        B = [0]*n
        # the value of A[i] becomes the index for counting
        # C now stores the no. of occurences of element A[i] in A
        for i in A:
            C[i] = C[i] + 1
        print i,C
        # prepare the indexes for reinsertion
        # Each position in C now holds the range of array position where a value will be placed
        i = 0
        while i < n:
            #print i
            C[i] = C[i] + C[i-1]
            i += 1
        print "Array position for each element",C
.
# the stability part of sort ???
        for j in xrange(n-1,0,-1):
            print "j",j,"A[j]:",A[j]
            B[C[A[j]]-1] = A[j]
            print B
            C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] - 1
            print C
        print B
        return B


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        A =[0,2,0,1,3,4,6,1,3,2]
        countingsort(A,len(A))
```

What are the real uses of counting sort in the real-world ?

Comment: *"Do you think that the below implementation is stable ?"* - have you tested it? What happened?

Comment: let me test out dictionary items. I tried with Integers which is not giving the correct picture, as they are all the same.

Comment: Counting sort is a fast way to sort an array of integers, which can be sorted from least significant byte to most significant byte, taking 4 passes for 32 bit integers and 8 passes for 64 bit integers. The algorithm needs to be modified if the array includes negative signed integers.

Comment: The sort should be stable. Note that the size of C should be based on the range of values in A. If the values in A range from 0 to 9, then the size of C should be 10. If the range is 0 to 255 (one byte), then the size of C should be 256. You could move the line  C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] - 1 up 2 lines and use B[C[A[j]]] = A[j] instead. You might consider changing the sort so that it goes from A[0] to A[n-1]. This means that C[0] = 0, C[1] = # 0's, C[2] = # 0's + # 1's, ...

Answer (score 0):

> What are the real uses of counting sort in the real-world ?

C++ example of a counting / radix sort for 32 bit unsigned integers. It makes one pass over the array, creating 4 sets of histograms in the matrix mIndex[][] based on the bytes of each integer in the array. Next it converts the histograms into indices. Then it does 4 radix sort passes, least significant byte to most significant byte. On my system, Intel 2600K 3.4ghz, sorting 16 million 32 bit unsigned integers takes about 1.5 seconds with a bottom up merge sort and about 0.5 seconds using this example radix sort.

```
//  a is input array, b is working array
uint32_t * RadixSort(uint32_t * a, uint32_t *b, size_t count)
{
size_t mIndex[4][256] = {0};            // count / index matrix
size_t i,j,m,n;
uint32_t u;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){         // generate histograms
        u = a[i];
        for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            mIndex[j][(size_t)(u & 0xff)]++;
            u >>= 8;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // convert to indices
        m = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < 256; i++){
            n = mIndex[j][i];
            mIndex[j][i] = m;
            m += n;
        }       
    }
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){             // radix sort
        for(i = 0; i < count; i++){     //  sort by current lsb
            u = a[i];
            m = (size_t)(u>>(j<<3))&0xff;
            b[mIndex[j][m]++] = u;
        }
        std::swap(a, b);                //  swap ptrs
    }
    return(a);
}
```